# How to make a ListView scrollable?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I have a problem with my application. I can't scroll it. The list move down but jump to the top after tapend.
I tried to set [layout: 'fit'](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?178160-List-scroll-issue), [height: '100%'](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135538-My-List-will-not-scroll-down-it-always-pops-back-up) and refresh scroll but it didn't help.
View:

```
Ext.define("Project.view.CatsList", {
  xtype: "cats-list",
  extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
  requires: [
     'Project.helper.NumberFormatter',
     'Project.store.Cats',
     'Project.model.Project',
     'Project.helper.TemplateFactory',
     'Project.Config',
     'Ext.XTemplate'
  ],

  config: {
     title: "Project",
     cls: "project-cats-list",

     itemCls: "project-cat-list-item",
     itemTpl: Project.helper.TemplateFactory.getCatTemplate(),
```

Main controller:

```
   Ext.define("Project.view.BaseNavigationView", {
      xtype: "bas-container",
      extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

      getAnimationDuration: function(){
         // timeout to complete render and unlock flags
         return 900;
      },

      // override push method
      push: function (view, callback) {
         if(typeof callback == 'function') {
            setTimeout(callback, this.getAnimationDuration());
         }

         return this.add(view);
      },

      removeView: function(view, destroy){
         var index = this.indexOf(view);
         if(index != -1) {
            this.doRemove(view, index, destroy);
         }
      },
```

Phone controller:

```
Ext.define('Project.view.phone.Main', {
      extend: 'Project.view.BaseNavigationView',
      xtype: 'main',
      requires: [
         'Project.view.CatList'
      ],
      config: {
         autoDestroy: true,
         fullscreen: true,

         items: [
            {
               xtype: 'category-list'
            }
         ]
      },

      initialize: function() {
         this.callParent(arguments);

         var bar = this.getNavigationBar();
         if(bar && typeof bar.hide == "function") {
            bar.hide();
         }
      },

      getListView: function(){
         return this.down('category-list');
      },
```

Can someone advice how to fix this issue?
Btw in [Ext.dataview.List](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List) docs application examples have same problem with scrolling.

P.S. I resolve this issue by updating Sencha Cmd and Sencha Touch to last version.

Comment: Can you provide us with some more code. It heavily depends on where the ListView is placed. Are you using a viewport? Does the container have a layout? Maybe you can write a Sencha Fiddle to show us what is going wrong: https://fiddle.sencha.com :)

Comment: My view based on Ext.dataview.List. And in sencha docs [http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List) same problem with scrolling in example apllications (btw Ext.dataview.List have a fit layout). Sorry I can't write my project on Fiddle cause it used sided API

Comment: You are walking into this bug I guess: http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/chrome-43-breaks-sencha-touch-modern-toolkit-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: Update Sencha Cmd and Sencha touch to 2.4.2 helps. Thank you very much!

Comment: NP! Good to hear that :)